# Divs are making the page too tall

Tags: html, screen

So, I have a page with multiple div's repositioned on the screen. The problem is, the page gets taller as I add a div to it.

Obs. This is the footer. *I mentioned it with a php include tag to add it to the rest of the page.

(Sorry about my english)

Html:

```
<div id="rodape_content">
<div id="conteudo"><br/>
        <center>
            <img src="img/sonhe_as_solucao.png" width="300" height="66"/>
        </center>
        <br/>

        <div id="modelo01">
            <p><img src="img/modelos/comercio.png" width="50" height="50" align="left"/>
                <font color="#fff">COMÉRCIO ELETRÔNICO
                    <p align="justify">Sites de comércio eletrônico (e-commerce/ loja virtual) é um grande diferencial
                        competitivo para qualquer empresa, independente do porte da mesma. Com a After Solutions, você
                        poderá vender suas mercadorias on-line com facilidade e profissionalismo, dispondo das mais
                        modernas ferramentas do mercado.</p>
                </font>
        </div>
        <div id="modelo02">
            <p><img src="img/modelos/dinamicos.png" width="50" height="50" align="left"/>
                <font color="#fff">SITE DINÂMICO (PHP)
                    <p align="justify">Sites dinâmicos, em PHP, são sites "programados" para uma finalidade específica,
                        seja gerenciar uma área do cliente ou então ter uma interface de manutenção do seu próprio
                        website. Exemplos de plataformas em PHP: Wordpress (gerenciamento de website), WHMCS
                        (gerenciamento de clientes e produtos) e PHPbb (gerenciamento de forum).</p>
                </font>
        </div>
        <div id="modelo03">
            <p><img src="img/modelos/blogs.png" width="50" height="50" align="left"/>
                <font color="#fff">BLOGS
                    <p align="justify">Os blogs, atualmente, destacam-se pela facilidade de adicionar e expor conteúdos.
                        Exemplos? Blogs de Humor integrados com as redes sociais, blogs de notícias, pessoais entre
                        outros. Na After Solutions, você tem a comodidade de ter um blog "desenhado" em sintonia com o
                        conteúdo postado.</p>
                </font>
        </div>
        <div id="modelo04">
            <p><img src="img/modelos/blogs.png" width="50" height="50" align="left"/>
                <font color="#fff">PORTFÓLIO
                    <p align="justify">Um portfólio, é a melhor maneira para um artista expor seu trabalho. A After
                        Solutions desenvolve portfólios para todo o tipo de artista, seja para músicos, pintores,
                        fotográfos... Além disso, é possível integrar seu portfólio com um blog, com uma loja virtual ou
                        ambos! Exponha, anuncie, venda sua obra! </p>
                </font>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body, td, th {
    color: #999;
    background-image: url(../img/fundo.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: "Arial Narrow", cursive;
}
#conteudo {
    width: 920px;
    margin: auto
}
#modelo01 {
    width:220px;
    height:250px;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url(../img/sub_cabecalho_bg.png);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;  /* for Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* for Webkit-Browsers */
    border-radius: 5px; /* regular */
    border: 2px solid #CCC;
    clear:both;
}
#modelo02 {
    width:220px;
    height:250px;
    position:relative;
    top: -254px;
    left:230px;
    background-image:url(../img/sub_cabecalho_bg.png);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;  /* for Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* for Webkit-Browsers */
    border-radius: 5px; /* regular */
    border: 2px solid #CCC;
    clear:both;
}
#modelo03 {
    width:220px;
    height:250px;
    position:relative;
    top: -508px;
    left:460px;
    background-image:url(../img/sub_cabecalho_bg.png);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;  /* for Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* for Webkit-Browsers */
    border-radius: 5px; /* regular */
    border: 2px solid #CCC;
    clear:both;
}
#modelo04 {
    width:220px;
    height:250px;
    position:relative;
    top: -762px;
    left:690px;
    background-image:url(../img/sub_cabecalho_bg.png);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;  /* for Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* for Webkit-Browsers */
    border-radius: 5px; /* regular */
    border: 2px solid #CCC;
    clear:both;
}
#rodape_content {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #099;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-top: 5px solid #ccc;
}
```

Picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's what `position: relative` does - it moves the elements from their original position without affecting the layout of the page.

You'd be better off achieving this layout using floats.  Since the four content boxes have similar styling, I'd also suggest giving them a common class name rather than assigning each a unique ID.